# RX: how to parallelize some long running tasks and synchronize others

Tags: .net, multithreading, system.reactive

I've been struggling with this for a while now. I have events that i'd like to process asynchronously (they are long running), however if the data passed from the event meets a condition (same id for example), i'd like the event to be processed synchronously and in order.

Is this something easily achievable with RX? Or do I need to implement my own thread synchronization and queuing?

Here is a code snippet that illustrates my problem:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var trigger = new EventTrigger();

        Observable.FromEvent<EventTrigger.OnNewDataHandler, int>(h => trigger.OnNewData += h, h => trigger.OnNewData -= h)
                  .Subscribe(LongRunning);

        // Should process id 1 synchorously and in order, and ids 2, 3, 4 in parallel
        trigger.RaiseEvent(1);
        trigger.RaiseEvent(2);
        trigger.RaiseEvent(1);
        trigger.RaiseEvent(1);
        trigger.RaiseEvent(3);
        trigger.RaiseEvent(4);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void LongRunning(int id)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1, 10) * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": " + id);
    }
}

public class EventTrigger
{
    public event OnNewDataHandler OnNewData;
    public delegate void OnNewDataHandler(int id);

    public void RaiseEvent(int id)
    {
        var handler = OnNewData;
        if (handler != null) handler(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be pretty easily done via [Punchclock](https://github.com/paulcbetts/punchclock), which internally uses Rx. Here's the only method of the only class:

```
IObservable<T> EnqueueObservableOperation(int priority, string key, IObservable<TDontCare> cancel, Func<IObservable<T>> asyncCalculationFunc);
```

Anything that has the same `key` parameter will run serialized in-order, but operations with different keys will run in parallel.

> As a rudely generalized rule of thumb, if you have "parallelize" in your question, Rx is typically not the answer!

I disagree :)

Answer (score 1):

Rx guarantees in-order non-concurrent handling of events per subscriber, so you just use two different subscriptions. Use one for synchronously handled events that just leverages using Rx semantics. This has to specify a TaskPoolScheduler (or similar) to avoid blocking on the current thread. Then use a second for asynchronously handled events that offloads to the task pool in the handler.

```
    var events = Observable.FromEvent<EventTrigger.OnNewDataHandler, int>(
        h => trigger.OnNewData += h,
        h => trigger.OnNewData -= h);

    events.Where(id => id == 1)
          .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
          .Subscribe(LongRunning);

    events.Where(id => id != 1)
          .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
          .Subscribe(LongRunningAsync);
```

With handlers:

```
private static void LongRunning(int id)
{
    DoWork(id);
}

private static void LongRunningAsync(int id)
{
    Task.Run(() => DoWork(id));        
}

private static void DoWork(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": started " + id);
    var random = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1, 10) * 1000);
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ": finished " + id);
}
```

Comment: Hi James, unfortunately id == 1 was just an example. I really want all events processed asynchronously unless an ID of the same value is already being processed, in which case I want the new event to be queued behind the first. I know how to accomplish this with a mutex and queue, but was hoping RX might have a simpler solutionl

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that detail, it read like certain event types meeting a condition would qualify for synchronous handling to me, rather than multiple buckets - but yes you are totally fighting the framework to encode that in the query. Queues filled from the subscription handler are the right way to go.

Comment: As a rudely generalized rule of thumb, if you have "parallelize" in your question, Rx is typically not the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to do your work and then project the result of it, then this works.

```
Observable.FromEvent<EventTrigger.OnNewDataHandler, int>(
    h => trigger.OnNewData += h, 
    h => trigger.OnNewData -= h
    )
    .GroupBy(i=>i)
    .Select(grp=>grp.ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default).SelectMany(i=>LongRunningTransform(i)))
    .Subscribe(result=>Console.WriteLine(result));
```

And here we just change the LongRunning OnNext handler to just be a projection

```
private static string LongRunningTransform(int id)
{
    var random = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1, 10) * 1000);
    return string.Format("{0:o} Id: {1} on thread {2}", 
            DateTime.Now ,
            id, 
            Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Comment: Lee, should that Select after the GroupBy be a SelectMany?

Comment: Yeah, that might be easier to understand (and run!)